# Inner join on a meta_value field

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce, entity-attribute-value

I would like to do an inner join on a meta_value field.

In the following code, I need to join 'enrolment' to the 'wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta' (OIM) table where the oim.meta_key='enrolment_id' and the meta_value= the id field in the 'enrolment' table.

The structure of the wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta is

- id
- meta_key
- meta_value

The structure of the enrolment table is:

- id
- firstname
- surname
- etc

Note in my example I pivot the OIM table fields from rows to columns.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
  O.order_item_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'class' THEN OIM.meta_value END) AS 'class',
  MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'fee-type' THEN OIM.meta_value END) AS 'fees',
  MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'enrolment_id' THEN OIM.meta_value END) AS 'eid'
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items O
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta OIM ON O.order_item_id = OIM.order_item_id
INNER JOIN enrolment E ON ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately enrolment_id is a meta_key value rather than a column of its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the meta key in the `ON` clause.

```
...
INNER JOIN enrolment e
           ON e.id = oim.meta_value
              AND oim.meta_key = 'enrolment_id'
...
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. The only problem is that it's making 'class' and 'fees' return as NULL. Any thoughts?